# Matlab - Can't call function because it says I'm trying to execute a script

Tags: matlab

In Matlab I defined a function called iReadImage it looks like:

function [outimag] = iReadImage(imaurl)

{code}

I used it for hours and everything seemed to work fine but then I changed one line and all of a sudden it didn't work anymore, even after I deleted that line nothing worked. It always tells me:

Attempt to execute SCRIPT iReadImage as a function:

/home/.../iReadImage.m

When I look at the file it says that it is 0kB....No idea why, I tried kind of everything, copied the function to a new function, rebooted my computer even tried it on other PCs. Two or three times it seemed to work again but never for long until I got the same error message.

Comment: ok now I tried to define a simple function: function out = ImPro(a) out=a+1;  I saved it at the same location as the other function and the same thing happened here! Is there a problem with the folder I want to save my functions in??

Comment: how are you calling the function? are you sending the right parameters? maybe you should try [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18IIZ/).

Comment: I call the function like iReadImage('path of image') or ImPro(2) and it doesn't work. The most suspicious thing is that the files are empty if I save them, close the the file and load them again.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is very particular about how its functions can be constructed.  The file functionname.m should start with the first line function [output] = functionname(input).  Otherwise, it will assume that it is dealing with a script and not a function.  Additionally, if your file is a function, you can declare within it, like:

```
function y = f(x)

    y = g(x) + 2;   

    function z = g(x)
    z = x.^2;
    end

end
```

However, if your file is a script, Matlab does not allow such function declarations.  One way to test this would be to trivially turn your existing script into a function (by wrapping it with a function with null input and output), and see if he same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you've changed your working directory (using e.g. `cd`).  You can only run functions that are in the current working directory, or in directories listed in [path](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/path.html).

To confirm, type `which iReadImage`.

Comment: I already tried which iReadImage and it's in my Current folder. As I said it used to work, I didn't change the path. But now I saved the file on the desktop and it works again.

Comment: Ok I'm getting nuts. Everything worked fine again but then I added following lines to my code: scarotim= imresize(rotim,outsize/insize);figure(1);image(scarotim); And now I get the same sh.. as before, I deleted the file, deleted these lines and saved it new but it won't work again!!!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have multiple iReadImage files in the directories where matlab searches for scripts and functions. If so it's likley that Matlab have found the wrong one (perhaps one with an error in it?) and tries to execute it.

Make sure you only have **one** copy of the file (check which directories Matlab searches in with `path`).

To find out from which directory Matlab will execute your function write `which <filename>`, that is, in your case `which iReadImage` and make sure the correct file is used.

You can also use `which iReadImage -all` to find all iReadImage files.

Comment: I tried which <filename> and there's only this one file. As I pointed out the thing that bothers me most is that after saving a file it says the file has size 0 bytes.

Comment: Okay, I guess the file that is 0 bytes you are referring to are the .m file? If so, have you checked it in notepad (or any other text editor since you seem to be running a Linux system :)?

Comment: Yes it's the .m file. Yes I checked it in notepad and it is empty. (I ran both Linux and Windows at the moment...Got the same problem)

Comment: If the file is empty it's obvious why you get that error message. If a .m file doesn't contain any code it's considered a script file, not a function as a function needs to have the function header. The question you should be asking isn't why you get the error message, but why the file is empty. Have you pasted the code in the .m file using a text editor, saved it and then tried to run the function?

Comment: Yes I pasted the code after this problem occured the first time. I also thought that might be the problem so I wrote a very simple function (no pasting) and it happened as well.

Comment: Posed it as a new Question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717666/matlab-after-saving-a-function-the-file-is-empty> thanks Niclas

Comment: Okay, hope you can solve it. One thing i came to think of, you do know that Matlab handles functions and scripts by the filename, not by the name you give in the function header? If they are different you could run into trouble..