# Matlab - After saving a function the file is empty

Tags: matlab

As I mentioned in another question [Matlab - Can't call function because it says I'm trying to execute a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715962/matlab-cant-call-function-because-it-says-im-trying-to-execute-a-script) I have a problem with calling a function. I (thanks to Niclas) found out that the problem is that when I save my function I save an empty file. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: why don't you show the code of saving your funciton to check what the errors are?

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the working directory?

Comment: I have permission (it worked before as I described in my other question, I'm sorry). I'm not using a code to save my function, simply open a m-file write my code and say Save as..

Comment: I had this problem once when working off of a poorly performing network drive.  I never got to the bottom of it .. I just learned to press ctrl-a ctrl-c ctrl-s instead of ctrl-s (poor workaround, but better than nothing).  Are you working on a network drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you have no more free space disk.

Comment: I don't think it is about free space disk, because the m file of matlab is few KB size, not that large.

Comment: ok, because everytime, this happened to me, it was because I used all my quota of disk space. There may be other possible reasons. It's hard to tell without doing some tests in front of your PC.

Comment: You are right concerning the performance of severl tests. we can't tell, but my comment was just a suggestion, not a fact.

Comment: Well that was it...embarassing. I'm sorry to have wasted your time:)